# Python: How to remove part of a string starting at a keyword for multiple lines?

Tags: python, string, file, text, replace

Here is my code:

```
with open('locations.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
for line in f:
    fo.write(line.replace('test'[:-1], ''))
```

I have a file with multiple lines of text:

```
This is a test the cat jumped around
This is another test the dog jumped under
This is a third test the cow jumped over
```

I want to be able to open the text file, and remove everything on each line after the word 'test'. So result would look like:

```
This is a test
This is another test
This is a third test
```

I am trying to use .replace() but using the paramter of -1 it just removed everything but the last letter in test. I am really not sure how to have the word 'test' be the input then have it remove the rest of the string after that on each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regex to find where "test" first appears in your string

```
with open('locations.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        index = re.search("test",line).span()[1]
        fo.write(line[:index ])
```

heres a breakdown:

`re.search("test",line)` searches for `"test"` in `line`

`re.search("test",line).span()` returns a tuple with the starting position and the ending position of what you wanted to find ("test")

`re.search("test",line).span()[1]` gives you the ending position of the word "test" in the line

finally `line[:index ]` gives you a slice of `line` up until the ending position of where it found "test"

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need regex if you know that 'test' appears in every line.  Just slice the string at the index of were `test` begins plus the length of `test`

```
with open('locations.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
for line in f:
    fo.write(line[:line.index('test') + len('test')])
```

Comment: this is probably the better option if you know for sure that "test" appears in every line. even if it doesnt you can probably just do a little error handling

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `split()`. `.split(separator, maxsplit)` is going to slice the string at the keyword and append them to a list which is returned then returned.
Set the maxsplit to 1 if there are multiple occurences of the keyword but you only need the first one.

```
with open('locations.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        new_string = line.split('test')[0] + "test"#  split removes the separator keyword
        fo.write(new_string)
```